# dcm4chee : Writing forward_priors.xml to forward prior studies based on patient ID

Tags: java, xml, dcm4che

I am bit new in writing routing rules in dcm4chee.

I have a requirement where the prior studies need to be selected based on patient ID of the current study and then routed.

As per my research, I need to have a forward_priors.xml to achieve that. I found only one sample online of this file and the conditions there needed specific values.

Can someone post a forward_priors.xml that would route studies by selecting them based on Patient ID?

I have tried putting together the forward_priors.xml but its not working.

Can someone please help me here?

Thanks,
Jasmeet Singh

Comment: Can you explain: not working?

Comment: I am not able to generate a forward_priors.xml but I have put in includePrior in my destination. Hence I cannot see any priors going through. I know I need to put in a forward_priors.xml but I cannot understand the content so that it only routes using patient ID.

Comment: Hi,

I am seeing this errror when it runs my forward_priors.xsl

2014-02-20 13:33:51,243 INFO  -> (Thread-93) [org.dcm4chex.archive.mbean.TemplatesService] Compiling Stylesheet C:\Users\dcm4chee-2.17.1-mysql\server\default\conf\dcm4chee-ae\forward_priors.xsl
2014-02-20 13:33:51,397 WARN  -> (Thread-93) [org.dcm4chex.archive.dcm.movescu.ForwardService2] Missing studyIUID attribute in destination element of forward_priors.xsl! Ignored!